# Deploying as ASP.NET website DLL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dll, deployment

a year ago I created and deployed a simple web app from visual studio 2012. This included a dll in the bin folder containing the code behind.
Fast forward one year and I need to make a small change to the .cs file.
I open the solution in VS2012, make my change and select build project. No bin folder and no dll are created. I try build website, rebuild website and anything obvious I can see but even though the build process works fine I do not end up with the bin folder or the dll. I have double checked the live site and the web site contains a bin folder and a dll rather than individual code-behind files.
Have I missed something obvious or fundamental here?

Comment: does the live site work ?

Comment: Yes live site is fine

Comment: Have solved this now. The compilation of the dll happens at the publish web site stage and not the build web site stage. Once I sorted out an issue with FTP I was able to publish to the live site and the dll was overwritten with my new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved this now. The compilation of the dll happens at the publish web site stage and not the build web site stage. Once I sorted out an issue with FTP I was able to publish to the live site and the dll was overwritten with my new one